# Is the June 2010 DX SDK really the latest?

Tags: directx

I have not been involved in game development, using the DirectX SDK, since around 2008. From the looks of it, the June 2010 release, of the DirectX SDK, is still the latest release. This release is more than two years ago, based on the name. Is this still the latest release, or has there been a naming convention change and I am missing something newer? I've seen mention of it being rolled into a Windows SDK, so I am confused and figured I would come here to ask.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's the latest version for Windows 7/Vista. In Windows 8 it has been merged with the Windows SDK you mentioned.

[More information on the merge into Windows SDK here...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: was half thinking when I made the edit. Should have been a comment to request the add, hope it's ok

Comment: Posted the response from a mobile phone in a hurry, so thanks for including the link!