# Is the new windows 8 sdk usable with visual c++ express 2010 on windows 7?

Tags: directx11, windows

This is inspired by and related to [Is the June 2010 DX SDK really the latest?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31808/is-the-june-2010-dx-sdk-really-the-latest) asked recently but it's a different question.

I won't likely be purchasing the full visual studio 2012 for C++, I intend to use the free visual c++ express 2012 that targets desktop applications when it is released so for now I'm using visual c++ express 2010 running on windows 7.

The latest directx11 sdk is the one included in the windows 8 SDK now, it's not a separate release any more.

So my question is, can I use the windows 8 SDK to build directx11 programs that work on windows 7 using visual studio express 2010 running on windows 7. Or do I need to stick to the final DirectX SDK release for now?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20151107174637/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/vcblog/archive/2012/03/25/10287354.aspx), yes you can.

EDIT:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx#Requirements lists Windows 7 as a supported OS

Comment: -1, that link doesn't say anything about the SDK working under Windows 7, only on VS2010 under Windows 8.

Comment: Fair enough. It's a bit obvious you can't make fully fledged Windows 8 Metro apps to run on Windows 7, but I've added a link that lists the supported OS's of the SDK. Since this question was mainly directed towards the DirectX side of things, I don't see any reason you can't use the libraries, especially as Windows 7 is a supported OS of the SDK (which a quick Google search would have told you).